# Ajax Send ID To Another HTML Page With AJAX To Create Where Clause

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-4

**UPDATED: MAY 17, 2017 9:50 AM**

I have two HTML page with both have AJAX way of fetching data via page load. But Now I want to send id to another HTML page to fetch data with where clause into my subcategory page that id are came from the category page. How do I need to it? Or what is the following codes I missed or I need to use?

How to create where clause between two html page with both ajax load?

I created a copy of this at https://github.com/Ailyn09/AJAX-Fetch

I use the following codes:

category.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    <title></title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--Font-awesome 4.7.0-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

    <div class="row" id="fetch_allcategory"></div>

    <!-- /.container -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fetch_allcategory').load('php/category_fetch.php', function(response, status, xhr ){

            });
            $("#footer").load("footer.html");               
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

category.php

```
<?php 
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '123', 'orderingsystem');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection error: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY category_name");
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>
    <div class="col-lg-3 product-category">
        <div class="card">
             <img class="card-img-top" id="image" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>" src="images/category/<?php echo $row['categoryimage'] ?>" alt="Card image cap" onclick="window.location.href = 'subcategory.html'">
            <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $row['category_name']?></h4>
                <p class="card-text"><?php echo $row['description'] ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php }
} 
?>

 <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#image").click(function(){
            var id =   $('#image').attr('value');
              $.post("subcategory.php",{catid: id },function(d){
                  console.log(d);
              });
          });
       });

</script>
```

subcategory.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    <title></title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--Font-awesome 4.7.0-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

    <div class="row" id="fetch_subcategory"></div>

    <!-- /.container -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fetch_subcategory').load('subcategory_fetch.php')           
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

subcategory.php

```
<?php 
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '123', 'orderingsystem');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection error: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
if (isset($_POST['catid'])) {
    $categoryid = $_POST['catid'];
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE categoryid = '{$_POST['catid']}' ORDER BY name");
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>
        <div class="col-lg-3 product-category">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/subcategory/<?php echo $row['subcategoryimages'] ?>" alt="Card image cap" onclick="window.location.href = 'products.html'">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $row['name'] ?></h4>
                    <p class="card-text"><?php echo $row['description'] ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php 
}

  }
} 
?>
```

Comment: I take trial and error for this if it's passing data to another PHP page then I   found that it caught nothing or it passed nothing. Whats is the problem with my codes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it may it's work fine.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$( "#fetch_allcategory" ).load( "category_fetch.php", function( response, status, xhr ) {

});
</script>
```

Go to 
category_fetch.php

```
<?php 
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '123', 'orderingsystem');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection error: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY category_name");
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>
    <div class="col-lg-3 product-category">
        <div class="card">
           <!---------- please check value for category id -------------->
             <img class="card-img-top" id="image" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>" src="images/category/<?php echo $row['categoryimage'] ?>" alt="Card image cap" onclick="window.location.href = 'subcategory.html'">
            <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $row['category_name']?></h4>
                <p class="card-text"><?php echo $row['description'] ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php }
} 
?>

 <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#image").click(function(){
            var id =   $('#image').attr('value');
              $.post("subcategory.php",{catid: id },function(d){
                  console.log(d);
              });
          });
       });

</script>
```

Then go to subcategory.php file

```
<?php 
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '123', 'orderingsystem');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection error: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$categoryid = $_POST['catid'];
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM subcategories where category_id = {$categoryid} ORDER BY name");
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>
    <div class="col-lg-3 product-category">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="images/subcategory/<?php echo $row['subcategoryimages'] ?>" alt="Card image cap" onclick="window.location.href = 'products.html'">
            <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $row['name'] ?></h4>
                <p class="card-text"><?php echo $row['description'] ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php   }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Sir @Md.Jewel Mia I want that when I click the image at category.html it will redirect to subcategory.html while sending id> In order for the codes at subcategory.html have a `WHERE` query and get only selected item base on what I click. How can I do that sir?

Comment: can you load this page?

Comment: Yes it load. But it load all in my database. When I click on category it will redirect to subcategory and LOAD ALL ITEM IN DATABASE. Because I have no WHERE clause. And I don't know how to do that using ajax. @Md.Jewel Mia

Comment: When you click image then you can send id then you can get supcategory.php

Comment: Yes thanks. send ID to subcategory.html or .subcategory.php. I just want to fetch data in **subcategory.html** base from the the **category** I selected.

Comment: <img class="card-img-top" id="image" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>" src="images/category/<?php echo $row['categoryimage'] ?>" alt="Card image cap" onclick="window.location.href = 'subcategory.html'">

Comment: please value check

Comment: Then write <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#click").click(function(){
     //var kk = $("#image").val();
   var id =   $('#image').attr('value');
     $.post("subcategory.php",{catid: id },function(d){
      console.log(d);
     });
    });
    });
</script>

Comment: then you will get in subcategory.php file

Comment: $_POST['catid'];

Comment: Sir please make a a copy of my codes with your changes because I cannot understand it when it in the comment. Please answer my question using the answer question button below. @Md.Jewel Mia

Comment: Please see answer

Comment: Check category id i don't know which primary key to yours please check it.

Comment: Yes sir I get it but in it didn't work. Wait I'm creating github repository. @Md.Jewel Mia

Comment: The repository of this problem is located at 
 https://github.com/Ailyn09/AJAX-Fetch

Comment: I follow your code  @Md.Jewel Mia the I got this `
Notice
: Undefined index: catid in
C:\xampp\htdocs\orderingsystem\php\subcategory_fetch.php
on line
6


Notice
: Trying to get property of non-object in
C:\xampp\htdocs\orderingsystem\php\subcategory_fetch.php
on line
8`

Comment: Okay I fixed that then I used the`if (isset($_POST['catid'])) {  # the condition here }` but it's show nothing or empty.

Comment: Please join on my github repository  at https://github.com/Ailyn09/AJAX-Fetch and make some edit on it by using a pull request or taking fork of it. Yes your codes are valuable there's some error. It's when I click the image at category.html it redirect to subcategory.html but it show nothing or empty  @Md.Jewel Mia.